# Java: keyCode, rawCode, primaryLevelUnicode, scancode, what are they?

Tags: java, jintellitype

I am trying to simulate the keyboard stroke. When I press the `-` key, I receive the following event.

What does the various codes mean?

> [KEY_PRESSED, 
>   keyCode=45, 
>   keyText=Minus, keyChar='-',
>   keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD, rawCode=189,
>   primaryLevelUnicode=45, scancode=12]

Comment: Can you show the code you have run which returns this output?

Comment: I'm really curious about why this was closed, specially as "too broad". I can't really figure out how there is a possibility of "too many possible answers". The printed codes does all have a specific meaning.

Comment: And the code are also useful to understand how keyboard event are handled in any programming languages.

Comment: @Arkanon It's a very simple piece of code. I just add a key event listener to a JFrame. This is what I see when I checked the content of `e` argument in the `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` method.

Answer (score 3):

- `KEY_PRESSED` is the event type.
- `keyCode` is the code as integer of the key. Note that not all characters have a keycode associated with them. For example, there is no keycode for the question mark because there is no keyboard for which it appears on the primary layer. You can get a list of each code [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).
- `keyText` is the text description of the character.
- `keyChar` is the typed char.
- `keyLocation` is the location of the key that originated this key event. Some keys occur more than once on a keyboard, e.g. the left and right shift keys. Additionally, some keys occur on the numeric keypad. This provides a way of distinguishing such keys.
- You can get the list of raw key code [here](http://whdload.de/docs/en/rawkey.html). Note that there exist raw code for humanly typed character, and virtual key code for processed keys.
- `primaryLevelUnicode` I believe this is the chart used to map the characters. Unicode have multiple levels of chart mostly usefull for comparison (collator).
- Each time you press a key, [`scancode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode) are sent to the computer to identify the key. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/what-does-raw-unraw-keyboard-mode-mean) for more details. You can get a list of scan codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Note that the `scancode` seems to be for MS Windows only as per comment in `KeyEvent`:

```
private transient long scancode = 0; // for MS Windows only
```

Comment: Did you mean to say that `rawCode` relates to the keyboard layer? The value for `keyCode` simply seems to refer to the Unicode code point value for the "hyphen-minus" symbol.

Comment: @Arkanon Yes that's what I meant, it's incorrect ?

Comment: You have said that `keyCode` relates to the keyboard layer, but I think you mean to say that `rawCode` relates to the keyboard layer. The value for `keyCode` relates to the Unicode code point, and for a question mark this value should be 63.

Comment: @Arkanon the key code for a question mark is not mapped, try it and you will see that printing the event display 0 for keycode which is default value.

Comment: The only value that will be mapped when typing a `?` is the `keyChar`. Each other will result in 0. `keyText` will result in unknown.